# How to get popular posts to appear in post carousel

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel

I have added the Owl Carousel to my Wordpress theme following this tutorial - http://www.web2feel.com/making-a-featured-post-carousel-slider-with-wp-customizer-controls/ - I have added the carousel correctly, but now I would like it to automatically show popular posts.  Right now it shows posts that are in a certain category, for example "news".  Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my carousel.php

```html
<div id="slider">
 
    <?php
    $carousel_cat = get_theme_mod('carousel_setting','1');
    $carousel_count = get_theme_mod('count_setting','4');
    $new_query = new WP_Query( array('showposts' => $carousel_count, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' )); ?>
 
    <div class="item">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'carousel-pic' ); ?></a>
        <h3> <?php the_title();?> </h3>
    </div>
 
    <?php 
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Changes to the carousel.php file will make up the trick over here to display the popular posts in carousel slider.

Here is a trick you shall follow it up and crack the code on.

```
<div id="slider"> 
<?php
$carousel_cat = get_theme_mod('carousel_setting','1');
$carousel_count = get_theme_mod('count_setting','4');
$month = date('m');
$year = date('Y');
$new_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => $carousel_count, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC')); ?>
<?php if ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post(); ?>
<div class="item">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
<?php // the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); Thumbnail (150 x 150 hard cropped) If you want anyother size you can change ?>
<h3> <?php the_title();?> </h3>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, No Popular Posts Found ' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: But will this show the most polar posts that are on my website in the carousel?

Comment: Add this line to the carousel.php file by replacing the existing line. `$new_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $carousel_cat  , 'showposts' => $carousel_count, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ));`

Comment: This will show up all the posts that are under Uncategorized based on the post views and hence it is called as Popular Posts..

Comment: Can I still add categories to the posts?  For example if all of my posts are under 3 main categories, Travel, Food, and Life.  I want this slider to show the popular posts out of all of my posts (white are categorized into either Travel, food, or life)

Comment: If you want to display poplar posts based on the visit count on all the Categories you have to alter the code that has been provided in the carousel.php. You should not select the Category in such cases. Since in the Customize option there is only normal select not the multi select. Hence you can remove up the select tag over to your plugin and display the post in the carousel as per the posts counts.

Comment: Referene: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/

Comment: Change the Query like this if you want to display all the posts under different category based on posts views: `$new_query = new WP_Query( array('showposts' => $carousel_count, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ));`

Comment: You have to remove up the category over to the query :)

Comment: I've updated my question and added the carousel.php file with the updated Query.  Is this what it should look like? (I really appreciate the help!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121953/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-p-and-user6738171).

Comment: Have updated the carousel.php file and resend it to you . If you find any hindrance   let me know we shall fix it.

Comment: Looking forward for your reply regarding Popular posts slider plugin that you have created. Sure it will work.

Comment: Correct code for carousel.php file has been added over to the question. :)

Comment: Hi Naresh, I was wondering if there is any way I could talk to you in a chat room?  I have a question on this code you helped me write a few weeks ago.  I would really appreciate it.